# Cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, scope

Let me first apologize.  I've been coding for a long time now, but I'm new to Java.  I feel like this should be a simple error, but I've been working on it for a half hour to no avail:

```
public String getHtml(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        WebPageFetcher fetcher = new WebPageFetcher("http://google.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("WebPageFetcher failed ...");
    }

    return "<div id=\"header\">" + fetcher.getPageContent() + "</div>";
}
```

Where WebPageFetcher is implemented as shown here:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=147

I'm getting an error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable fetcher
location: class myclass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fetcher is visible only in the block where it was declared, the try block.  Try declaring before the block so it will be visible throughout the method:

```
WebPageFetcher fetcher = null;
try {
    fetcher = new WebPageFetcher("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: If you do that, you definitely need to add an if statement to check if `fetcher` is null outside of the try-catch.  The alternative is to move the return statement within the try block and do some action if an exception is raised (such as rethrow the exception, return null, etc)

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 1):

On the return the variable `fetcher` is out of scope.

Try:

```
public String getHtml(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
         WebPageFetcher fetcher = new WebPageFetcher("http://google.com");
         // return within scope
         return "<div id=\"header\">" + fetcher.getPageContent() + "</div>";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("WebPageFetcher failed ...");
    }
     return /*something that make sense*/ "<html>500</html>";
}
```

Comment: Again, if you're admitting that an exception could happen, then this is an NPE waiting to happen...

Comment: Yeap, I pretty much only worried about the scope, but the return should go in the try/catch... editing...

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the variable `fetcher` is only within the most enclosing scope, i.e. the most nested pair of brace (`{ }`) surrounding it.  Therefore, it no longer exists by the time you get to the `return` statement where you're trying to use it.