# Why my program no work ? keep getting cannot find symbol error?

Tags: java, inheritance

I keep getting cannot find symbol error when trying to create the subclass h object in my main code. Would someone please be able to help ? Thanks.

It seems like the main program is accepting the inhtt object but when I try to call h object it says that it cannot find symbol and asks me to create the h object.

```
public class inhtt {
   //class methods
  public  int thing; 
    public int stuff ;
    public int otherstuff;

  // constructor based on parameters
 public inhtt( int x, int y, int z){
        thing = x;
        stuff = y;
        otherstuff = z;
    }    
 void showmain (){
    System.out.println("thing is " + thing);
    System.out.println("stuff is " + stuff);
    System.out.println("otherstuff is " + otherstuff);
}

public class h extends inhtt {
  int beard; 
  h( int x, int y, int z, int a){
      super(x,y,z);
        beard = a;
  }
  void shownewa(){
    System.out.println("beard is" +beard);  
 }
}
}



 * @author New User
 */
public class runraffharsh {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     inhtt base = new inhtt(1,1,1);
     base.showmain();

     h = new h(1,1,1,1);
     h.shownew();

//      raff beard = new raff(1,1,1,1);
//     beard.showbeard();
//     

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the errors that you are getting?

Comment: You are calling `h.shownew()` whereas the class `h` has a method called `shownewa()` - typo maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951867/cannot-find-symbol-error

Comment: yeah a typo, had to change the names of things before post... it doesn't like the h = new h(1,1,1,1); line

Comment: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable h

Comment: Your `h` class is defined inside your `inhtt` class. You would reference it as `inhtt.h`. You also don't declare an `h` variable anywhere and can't assign to a class' name like it's a variable.

Comment: You have at least three problems. 1) `h` is an inner class of `inhtt`. 2) You're assigning a value to `h` but you've never declared a variable called `h`. 3) You're trying to call `shownew()` when that method doesn't exist. All of these would be a lot easier to see if you used conventional, meaningful names and sensible indentation.

Comment: when i move the h class to a new file it works fine, would you be able to explain how i can initiate  nested class as i don't understand it from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code:

1. `h` is a inner class to `inhtt`.  Since it is not static, you'll need to use something like `base.new h(1,1,1,1);` to instantiate it.
2. You need to declare a variable to assign your new `h` instance to.  Try something like `inhtt.h h = base.new h(1,1,1,1);` for the whole line.
3. `h` (the class) has no method named `shownew`.  It has a method named `shownewa`.
4. `runraffharsh` and `inhtt` are both public classes.  They need to be in separate files.
5. The comment block at the top of `runraffharsh` is not opened properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with inherited class h's reference. And you defined showewa() but tried to access shownew()